# JSF Chrome Save Password on Login form

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, jsf-2, passwords, save

How do I get my JSF login page to prompt Chrome to save password?

```
    <h:form id="login-form" class="form login-form">

                <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Email:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.j_username}" id="j_username"
                    required="true">
                </p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password:" />
                <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.j_password}" id="j_password"
                    required="true">

            <p:commandButton id="loginButton"
                value="Login"  action="#{loginBean.login}" />

        </h:form>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Go into settings and tell Chrome you want it to save for that site.

Comment: please try to set autocomplete="off" in inputSecret and username inputText

Comment: @Laabidi: Huh? Don't you rather mean "on"? OP want to enable the save of password, not to disable it. Even then, that part is not related to the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC ah of course it should be "on". sorry, I lost my attention. And I think not using autocomplete will also affect browser behaviour when submitting the login form. May be the problem is only because of ajax (as you said in your answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off ajax by `ajax="false"` on the `<p:commandButton>`. For security reasons, Chrome won't save passwords of ajax login forms.

If that also doesn't help, then go to *Settings > Show advanced settings > Manage  saved passwords* (or go to `chrome://settings/passwords` in Chrome) and scroll to the very bottom of the list to see if the site in question isn't accidently covered by "Never saved" list.